# Why is my $profile empty when using Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm just getting started with PowerShell and i'm running into a strange problem. If I login to a box using remote desktop and fire up an instance of PowerShell and type `$profile` I see this: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`.

If on my local machine i run `Enter-PSSession compName` and then execute `$profile` nothing is returned at all. Is there something I'm missing here?

Both machines have the same version of PowerShell (4.0) both machines have an execution policy of RemoteSigned.

Comment: Profiles are not loaded for remote sessions.

Comment: Ok so maybe i'm asking the wrong question. If i want to load a snap-in on start of a session how do i swing that?

Comment: An actual snap-in, or a module?

Comment: The command i run to set it up is `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell` so i assume it's a snap-in i'm unaware of any modules for TFS

Comment: You can register a session configuration on the remote machine with `Register-PSSessionConfiguration` and use the `-ModulesToImport` parameter to specify modules and snap-ins to import by default. Alternatively, just run `Add-PSSnapin` manually after `Enter-PSSession`